# SQL Server: Why xp_cmdshell is disabled by default?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

What are the security reasons that extended stored procedure xp_cmdshell is disabled by default?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find an explanation in the `Permissions` section of the SQL Server [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175046.aspx), where it states that:

> Because malicious users sometimes
>   attempt to elevate their privileges by
>   using xp_cmdshell, xp_cmdshell is
>   disabled by default.

You can find a more detailed explanation in the [SQL Server Security](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlsecurity/archive/2008/01/10/xp-cmdshell.aspx) blog. A brief excerpt from the blog states:

> In many cases, people enable
>   xp_cmdshell and grant access to it to
>   non-sysadmin principals in order to
>   perform one or two operations on the
>   system without realizing that the user
>   with access to it can execute any
>   arbitrary command, and in some cases,
>   effectively escalate his/her
>   privileges to sysadmin or even box
>   administrator - obviously a situation
>   that is less than desirable. 
>   Xp_cmdshell is really difficult to
>   control effectively, and even auditing
>   its usage may still allow the attacker
>   to abuse its power for some time until
>   the trail of this abuse is found, and
>   at that point the damage may already
>   be done.