# issue with a Exec master .. cmdshell statement in sql server

Tags: .net, sql-server

I am having trouble getting an exe to work from an exec master cmdshell statement in sql server.

The EXE works fine when I double click it. But when I try to run it with this command in SQL server it does not execute.

```
EXEC master..xp_cmdshell 'Path\Program.exe'
```

The program itself is very simple--it is just supposed to send an email alert using an in-house DLL. If it hits an error, it should write that error to a file in the current directory. (Eventually, I want it to set it up to run via a trigger when records are inserted into a particular table).

When I run the program with the statement above, the program does not print out an error message (as shown below) or send an email. How can I tell if it is executing? Hitting an error? What could be going on? The program itself is working properly when I run it via double clicking the path\program.exe.

```
Imports System.IO

Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Try
            EmailSenderDLL.EmailSender.send(15, "Alert Text.")
        Catch e As Exception
            File.WriteAllText(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() & "\" & Now.Year & Now.Month & Now.Day & Now.Millisecond, e.Message & vbNewLine & e.StackTrace)
        End Try

    End Sub

End Module
```

What steps can I take to fix this?

Comment: Why are you not using SQL Servers build in mail capabilities?

Comment: We dont have an in-house email server, so we send the alert to google's server via .net code. I am using sql server 2005. Is there is a way to send emails w/o an email server?

Comment: For security reasons, disable xp_cmdshell. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3797036/sql-server-why-xp-cmdshell-is-disabled-by-default  http://www.iderware.com/sql-security-disable-sql-xp_cmdshell Run exe's from the sql agent. Use database mail for email notifications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use database-mail with a google account: https://blogs.msdn.com/b/suhde/archive/2009/07/12/how-to-configure-sql-server-database-mail-to-send-email-using-your-windows-live-mail-account-or-your-gmail-account.aspx?Redirected=true

Make sure you open the right port (587) in you firewall to allow SQL Server to talk to google.